# IE not receiving data when receiving json response

Tags: jquery, json

Am running a javascript function that gets data from a rest server and returns it to another function. On Chrome and firefox this is working perfectly but on any version of IE(why am i not suprised) the function doesn't work...below is the code

```
function getTotalCounts() {
    var swings = '';
    var serviceUrl = 'http://urldata.com/getdata';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: "{}",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery.each(data.InteractiveBlockList, function (i, val) {
                swings = new Array(val.ActivationDay, val.GrassBlockCount, val.GrassSquareMeters, val.InstagramCount, val.PublicTweetCount, val.SwingCount);
                var gettotalcounts;
            });
            grassification(swings)
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea on what am doing wrong?

Comment: are you gettin any errors in ie ??

Comment: no errors in ie...just no data. If I do alert(swings) I get the data response from the other browsers apart from IE

Answer (score 0):

I would not be surprised your problem come from the fact you are sending a string **"{}"** as data. Try to send an empty object instead:

```
data: {}, //no quotes
```

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry...i dont understand

Comment: In your ajax config, you have data: "{}",  replace this with:      data: {},

Answer (score 0):

data is optional in ajax.. so if you don't need to send any information to server then no need of using it at all.comment your ajax `data` options

```
 //data="{}";
```

and make sure you close the script end with `;`.

```
grassification(swings);
          //----------^----here
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out what the problem is. First I added an error call to see what error it was. In Chrome/Firefox there was no error, in IE I got a 'no transport error'. After a bit of googling it turns out the problem was due to cross domain scripting, this blog gives a better explanation http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00660/force-jquery-1-5-to-always-allow-cross-site-scripting

Adding `jQuery.support.cors = true;` before making the ajax call fixed the problem. Weird how it totally refused to work on all versions of IE but thats IE for you!